# phpunit with laravel on vagrant box

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, phpunit, vagrant

I'm having trouble getting phpunit to work on my vagrant box. I provisioned it with puphpet and manage my laravel project with composer.

The problem is that when I `require-dev` phpunit, i can only run it as `sudo vendor/bin/phpunit`. Without sudo I get permission denied (chmod doesn't seem to change the permissions) and simply typing `phpunit` throws a not found error.

My composer.json:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*"
},
```

Ultimately I want to use phpunit with phpstorm but if I can't get it to work on my VM, that nice integration is still somewhat out of reach.

Comment: Check the user that phpunit belongs to, it should be vagrant. Also, are you logging in as 'vagrant'?

Comment: @vascowhite the user is www-data just as the rest of the laravel files. vagrant does belong to the www-data group

Answer (score -2):

Can't you install phpunit as a programm on your box? Like with

```
sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

Then you can call it from any directory.